# Suche den Roman, aus welchem Twain das Beispiel trennbarer Verben entnahm

Tags: quotes

Ich las vor gar nicht mal so kurzem *The Awful German Language* von Mark Twain. Er verwendet in diesem Schriftstück einen Ausschnitt aus einem von ihm nicht genannten Roman, dessen Titel aufzufinden, ich nicht imstande war, da er den Ausschnitt für sein Traktat anscheinend selbst ins Englische übersetzt hat. Vielleicht ist aber auch einfach der Romantext noch nicht im Internet auffindbar oder sogar verloren.
Weiß zufällig jemand hier Genaueres über den Roman? Titel und Autor ggf. Erscheinungsjahr wären äußerst hilfreich. Vielen Dank fürs Lesen.

> ### Textstelle nach Twains Übersetzung
>
> The trunks being now ready, he de- after kissing his mother and sisters, and once more pressing to his bosom his adored Gretchen, who, dressed in simple white muslin, with a single tuberose in the ample folds of her rich brown hair, had tottered feebly down the stairs, still pale from the terror and excitement of the past evening, but longing to lay her poor aching head yet once again upon the breast of him whom she loved more dearly than life itself, parted.

> ### Textstelle als Rückübersetzung aus dem englischen
>
> Die Koffer waren gepackt, **und er reiste**, nachdem er seine Mutter und seine Schwestern geküsst und noch ein letztes Mal sein angebetetes Gretchen an sich gedrückt hatte, das, in schlichten weißen Musselin gekleidet und mit einer einzelnen Nachthyazinthe im üppigen braunen Haar, kraftlos die Treppe herabgetaumelt war, immer noch blass von dem Entsetzen und der Aufregung des vorangegangenen Abends, aber voller Sehnsucht, ihren armen schmerzenden Kopf noch einmal an die Brust des Mannes zu legen, den sie mehr als ihr eigenes Leben liebte, **ab**.

---

Ab hier nur noch mein Rechtfertigungsversuch dafür, dass ich diese Frage hier stelle:
Ich bin mir im Klaren, dass diese Frage hart an der Grenze dieses Forums ist ("Anything not directly related to the German language", wie es in der Einführungsseite steht), allerdings sah ich hier auch schon Fragen darüber, was z. B. auf einem vermeintlichen Grabstein stand. Ich hoffe sehr, dass die Frage als zulässig angesehen wird, da ich nicht davon ausgehe, dass es eine Community im Internet gibt, die mir eher helfen kann.

Comment: Es *könnte* sich um die Erzählung "Der billige Kunstrichter", einen einfachen Fortsetzungsroman in der "Zeitung für die elegante Welt" handeln. Dort kommt ein Gretchen und ein Lessing mit Schwestern und Abreise vor. Wahrscheinlich hat sich Twain nicht gerade ein berühmtes Meisterwerk der deutschen Literatur ausgesucht, der Satzbau (wenn auch sicher von Twain übertrieben) läßt darauf schliessen.

Comment: @tofro Mal Thomas Mann gelesen?

Comment: @sgf Ich schon. Aber Mark Twain ziemlich sicher nicht. *The Awful German Language* stammt aus dem Jahr 1880, da war Thomas Mann 5 Jahre alt. Von daher verstehe ich nicht ganz, was Thomas Mann mit dieser Frage zu tun haben könnte.

Comment: @tofro Die ersten Sätze von *Effie Briest* sind ein gutes Beispiel für solche Bandwurmsätze in einem bekannten Buch. Wobei es sich danach normalisiert und die Einleitung somit auch absichtlich lange Sätze hat. Man darf bei dieser Geschichte nicht vergessen, dass das Englische im 19. Jahrhundert gerade dabei war, den Stil zu kurzen Sätzen zu wechseln - zu Twains Zeiten haben sicher auch noch einige so schwülstig geschrieben.

Comment: @tofro Das Zitat scheint mir nicht aus "Der billige Kunstrichter" zu sein. Zumindest kann ich die Stelle in dem Text nicht finden.

Comment: @tofro Was Chieron sagt - Verschwurbelter Satzbau und hohe Literatur sind wahrhaftig kein Widerspruch.

Comment: @sgf Da gebe ich dir recht - trotzdem dürfte sich Mr. Twain nicht mit einer Koryphäen der deutschen Literatur angelegt haben, wenn es ihm nur um die Klammer eines trennbaren Verbs ging...

Comment: War Twain ein Feigling? Um einen Punkt zu machen würde man sich gerade eine Koryphäe herauspicken.

Comment: @userunknown aber keine, die erst 5 Jahre alt ist und erst noch eine wird...

Comment: @Tofro: Der Kommentar hat von mir schon einen Pfeil hoch bekommen.

Answer (score 4):

Mark Twain had fitfully studied the German language in school, as had many American schoolchildren of the 19th century during the extensive migration of Germans to America from all parts of Germany. He was very familiar with what is involved for a student learning to read, write, and speak the German language; that is what his satirical and very, very, humorous monograph is all about.

In this part of his monograph "**The Trouble With The German Language**" he was writing about how the Germans love their separable prefixes, and how to the English-speaking ear they are so illogical.  Remember, Mark Twain was well-known and loved for his use of satire in his writings, and not above creating fictional texts from which he could 'cite' in his satires.  So here is the relevant text of what Twain thought about those prefixes:

> A favorite one is **reiste ab** -- which means departed. Here is an example which I culled from a novel and reduced to English:
>
> "The trunks being now ready, he **DE**- after kissing his mother and sisters, and once more pressing to his bosom his adored Gretchen, who, dressed in simple white muslin, with a single tuberose in the ample folds of her rich brown hair, had tottered feebly down the stairs, still pale from the terror and excitement of the past evening, but longing to lay her poor aching head yet once again upon the breast of him whom she loved more dearly than life itself, **PARTED**."

So I believe the answer to this question is simply this:  *There is no citation because there was no 'novel' that Twain says he culled his sentence from.*  That novel and his illustrative, Victorian-style, sentence are purely a work of fiction from Twain's exceptionally creative mind, a creation he used to illustrate his point.

And by the way,"**The Trouble With The German Language**" is a great and totally humorous read for students learning the German language, English-speaking students or otherwise.

Google it!

Answer (score 1):

Hier ist mein Antwort jetzt ins Deutchesprache:

Mark Twain hatte die deutsche Sprache in der Schule sorgfältig studiert, wie viele amerikanische Schulkinder des 19. Jahrhunderts bei der umfangreichen Migration von Deutschen nach Amerika aus allen Teilen Deutschlands. Er war sehr vertraut mit dem, was für einen Schüler gehört, der lernt, die deutsche Sprache zu lesen, zu schreiben und zu sprechen; das ist, was seine satirische und sehr, sehr, humorvolle monographie ist.

In diesem Teil seiner Monographie "The Trouble With The German Language" schrieb er darüber, wie die Deutschen ihre trennbaren Präfixe lieben und wie man das englischsprachige Ohr so ​​unlogisch ist. Denken Sie daran, Mark Twain war bekannt und geliebt für seine Verwendung von Satire in seinen Schriften, und nicht über die Erstellung von fiktiven Texten, aus denen er in seinen Satiren "zitieren" konnte. Also hier ist der relevante Text von was Twain über diese Präfixe gedacht hat:

Ein Favorit ist reiste ab - was bedeutet, abgereist. Hier ist ein Beispiel, das ich aus einem Roman entnommen und auf Englisch reduziert habe:

"Die Koffer waren jetzt fertig, er DE - nach dem Küssen seiner Mutter und Schwestern, und noch einmal drückte er auf seinen Busen seinen verehrten Gretchen, der in einem einfachen weißen Musselin gekleidet war, mit einer einzigen Tuberose in den reichlichen Falten ihres reichen braunen Haares, hatte schwach die Treppe hinuntergestürzt, immer noch blass vor dem Schrecken und der Aufregung des vergangenen Abends, aber Sehnsucht, ihren armen, schmerzenden Kopf noch einmal auf die Brust zu legen, die sie liebte, liebte das Leben selbst, -PARTED. "

Also glaube ich, dass die Antwort auf diese Frage einfach das ist: Es gibt kein Zitat, weil es keinen "Roman" gab, den Twain sagt, dass er seinen Satz aus. Dieser Roman und sein illustrativer, viktorianischer Satz sind nur ein Werk der Fiktion von Twains außergewöhnlich kreativem Verstand, einer Schöpfung, die er früher verdeutlichte.

Und übrigens, "The Trouble With The German Language" ist eine großartige und total humorvolle Lektüre für Studenten, die die deutsche Sprache sprechen, englischsprachige Studenten oder sonst.

Google es.
(Und tschüss!)